# Use a workflow to filter a list

Tags: list, workflow, office-365, excel, filter

I have a spreadsheet that contains numerous products, each one with a unique PN, desc and price.  There is similarity between products, contained in additional columns with simple YES or NO values assigned depending on their function.

What I want to do is create a list that asks questions and a workflow kicks off and based on the responses filters the YES and NO columns until there is only 1 option available for the user and displays the results.

I am thinking I will need to have a Master list with the data in and then reference it from another list, but am unsure if this is right or how to do it.

As you can probably tell, I am a noob, so welcome all help.

I am using SharePoint 2013 as part of O365.

Answer (score 0):

A workflow doesn't sound like the best tool to achieve what you're attempting, in my opinion. I would embed some javascript in the form template to dynamically hide/show options based upon user input. To my knowledge, a workflow cannot manipulate a live form (one that a user is inputting data into).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ask questions and have user responses in SharePoint, I would recommend to use Survey list.

Here are few references: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-survey-ea52a787-822e-4f7e-b5ed-77bb14df3aba